# Check if Android application was recreated in the custom Application class

Tags: android

Is it possible to check if the application has been recreated after being killed by the system (for example in low memory conditions)?

For the `Activity` it is very easy - we just need to check if `Bundle` passed in `onCreate` is `null` or not. Is it possible from the custom `Application` class? Ideally I'd like to know this information inside `Application.onCreate()` method.

Comment: you can check to see if onDestroy gets called. set something in shared pref. then on create check it.

Comment: But with this method I don't know if `Activity` is destroyed by user (by clicking back button for example) or by system due to low memory conditions

Comment: users, when clicking the back button is usually onpause/onstop. but yes, u cant tell if android called destory or user